# PUT binary data to a remote server

Tags: node.js

What I am trying to do is to translate this `curl` command into Node.js code

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:" --data-binary @slug.tgz "https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/herokuslugs/heroku.com/v1/xyz"
```

I have been fiddling with Node's built-in [`https.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) and the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) lib for more than a hour and still haven't figured that out.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem earlier. I got it work by changing from `fs.createReadStream` to `fs.readFile`. Here's a quick sample of what I did.

```
fs.readFile('@slug.tgz', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  options = {
    url: 'https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/herokuslugs/heroku.com/v1/xyz',
    body: data
  }

  request.put(options, function (err, message, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

When I used `fs.createReadStream` I got an error from Amazon. Also make sure you first create a slug through the platfrom API and use the `url` from the blog in the response.

Comment: i wonder why this works, and what is the issue with createReadStream

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:" --data-binary @slug.tgz "https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/herokuslugs/heroku.com/v1/xyz"
```

i'm not positive this works but this is what I would try first ([the third example in the request docs](https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming)):

```
fs.createReadStream('@slug.tgz').pipe(request.put('https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/herokuslugs/heroku.com/v1/xyz'))
```

you might also want to use amazon's [official node library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) as I demonstrate in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19887357/1380669)

Comment: I got a `{ [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }` error.

Answer (score 0):

following code works for me

```
var options = {
        url: <url>,
        method: "PUT",
    };

    fs.createReadStream(file_path).pipe(
        request(options, (err, response) => {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            var body = JSON.parse(response.body);
        })
    )
```