# NodeJS How do I Download a file to disk from an aws s3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, disk

My goal:

Display a dialog box prompting the user to save a file being downloaded from aws.

My problem:

I am currently using awssum-amazon-s3 to create a download stream. However I've only managed to save the file to my server or stream it to the command line... As you can see from my code my last attempt was to try and manually set the content disposition headers which failed. I cannot use res.download() as the headers have already been set?

How can I achieve my goal?

My code for node:

```
app.post('/dls/:dlKey', function(req, res, next){
        // download the file via aws s3 here
        var dlKey = req.param('dlKey');

        Dl.findOne({key:dlKey}, function(err, dl){
            if (err) return next(err);
            var files = dl.dlFile;

            var options = {
                BucketName    : 'xxxx',
                ObjectName    : files,
            };

            s3.GetObject(options, { stream : true }, function(err, data) {
                // stream this file to stdout
                fmt.sep();
                data.Headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment';
                console.log(data.Headers);
                data.Stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.pdf'));
                data.Stream.on('end', function() {
                    console.log('File Downloaded!');
                });
            });
        });

        res.end('Successful Download Post!');
    });
```

My code for angular:

```
$scope.dlComplete = function (dl) {
        $scope.procDownload = true;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/dls/' + dl.dlKey
        }).success(function(data/*, status, headers, config*/) {
            console.log(data);
            $location.path('/#!/success');
        }).error(function(/*data, status, headers, config*/) {
            console.log('File download failed!');
        });
    };
```

The purpose of this code it to let users use a generated key to download a file once.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't download a file to the user's disk via AJAX requests (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/2137601) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683228/2137601) for instance). What you can do instead is make the user send a POST FORM with the `dlKey` data.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This is the entire code using streaming on the latest version of aws-sdk

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.send('You did not say the magic word');
});


app.get('/s3Proxy', function(req, res, next){
    // download the file via aws s3 here
    var fileKey = req.query['fileKey'];

    console.log('Trying to download file', fileKey);
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update(
      {
        accessKeyId: "....",
        secretAccessKey: "...",
        region: 'ap-southeast-1'
      }
    );
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var options = {
        Bucket    : '/bucket-url',
        Key    : fileKey,
    };

    res.attachment(fileKey);
    var fileStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
    fileStream.pipe(res);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('S3 Proxy app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: I had no idea `.createReadStream()` was a thing. Thank you for this example!

Comment: how can I download that from the client? The stream works, and I can see on the client's console. But how can I open the "download dialog" by client side, to let the user actually get the file? I guess something with the Blob, but I can't get how

Comment: `var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpg' });`  where data is the response caught by angular side.  It downloads the file, the size is correct, but file is corrupted and impossible to open

Comment: @DeLac - Were you able to get the file downloaded from angular?

Comment: `.createReadStream()` is no longer available.

Answer (score 26):

Simply create a [ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options) from S3, and [WriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions) for the location to which you wish to download.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.loadFromPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.json'));
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
  region: AWS.config.region
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {
  Bucket: '<your-bucket>', 
  Key: '<path-to-your-file>'
};
const readStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 's3data.txt'));
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

Answer (score 24):

This code worked for me with the most recent library:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var s3Params = {
    Bucket: 'your bucket',
    Key: 'path/to/the/file.ext'
};
s3.getObject(s3Params, function(err, res) {
    if (err === null) {
       res.attachment('file.ext'); // or whatever your logic needs
       res.send(data.Body);
    } else {
       res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: `"aws-sdk": "^2.7.20",`

Comment: data.Body is a Buffer which supports toString(). The object returned by the getObject did not have the .createReadStream() method shown in the example from 2015. There data object in the call back did not have the data.Stream attribute shown in the example from 2014.

Comment: data is undefined. I guess, data.Body is nothing but result.Body or response.Body. If that is the case, Please update the answer...

Answer (score 12):

Using aws SDK v3

```
npm install @aws-sdk/client-s3
```

download code

```
import { GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
/**
 * download a file from AWS and send to your rest client
 */
app.get('/download', function(req, res, next){
    var fileKey = req.query['fileKey'];

    var bucketParams = {
        Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
        Key: fileKey,
    };

    res.attachment(fileKey);
    var fileStream = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams));
    // for TS you can add: if (fileStream.Body instanceof Readable)
    fileStream.Body.pipe(res)
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You've already figured what's most important to solve your issue: you can pipe the file stream coming from S3 to any writable stream, be it a filestream… or the response stream that will be sent to the client!

```
s3.GetObject(options, { stream : true }, function(err, data) {
    res.attachment('test.pdf');
    data.Stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Note the use of [`res.attachment`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.attachment) that will set the correct headers. You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883629/2137601) regarding streams and S3.

Comment: Thanks for the quick post!
The code you suggested compiles file, and looks as-if it should work however it still isn't prompting me with a download dialog on safari or chrome! I can't figure out why since it should have an the attachment header now

Comment: Isn't this behavior (prompting the user for the download location) related to the browser's configuration?

Comment: Yes but even with the correct config I'm not getting a prompt. It's not even downloading(server or to local). I'll update my question with my angular code too because maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Can you try [this simple gist](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/9323085) and check if the file is correctly downloaded using your browser? If yes, this means that your Angular code is the issue

Comment: I ran it but got: "Error: ENOENT, open 'test.pdf'"

Comment: Woops, just create a sample `test.pdf` file, or change the filename in your code so that it points to an existing file

Comment: Worked like a charm! Must be my angular code then!
-Thanks for the all the help :D

Comment: `GetObject` is not a function

Answer (score 5):

For this I use `React frontend` and `node js backend`. Frontend I use Axios. I used this click the button download file.

==== Node js backend code (AWS S3) ======

//inside `GET` method I called this function

```
    public download = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const keyName = req.query.keyName as string;
    if (!keyName) {
        throw new Error('key is undefined');
    }
    const downloadParams: AWS.S3.GetObjectRequest = {
        Bucket: this.BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: keyName
    };

    this.s3.getObject(downloadParams, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }
        res.send(data.Body);
        res.end();
    });
};
```

====== React js frontend code ========

//this function handle download button `onClick`

```
  const downloadHandler = async (keyName: string) => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get( //here use axios interceptors
    `papers/paper/download?keyName=${keyName}`,{
      responseType:'blob', //very very important dont miss (if not downloaded file unsupported to view)
    }
  );
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf"); //change "file.pdf" according to saved name you want, give extension according to filetype
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
};
```

------ OR (if you are using normal axios and not [axios interceptors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#interceptors)) -----

```
axios({
   url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/example.pdf',
   method: 'GET',
   responseType: 'blob', // very very important
}).then((response) => {
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
   const link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = url;
   link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
});
```

For more refer below articles
1. [article 1](https://pretagteam.com/question/download-file-from-express-api-using-react-and-axios)
2. [article 2](https://dev.to/doxomo/how-to-download-files-with-axios-2b8g)

Comment: "responseType: 'blob', // very very important" This line saved my day! Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Using express, based on Jushua's answer and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_GetObject_section.html

```
  public downloadFeedFile = (req: IFeedUrlRequest, res: Response) => {
    const downloadParams: GetObjectCommandInput = parseS3Url(req.s3FileUrl.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    logger.info("requesting S3 file  " + JSON.stringify(downloadParams));
    const run = async () => {
      try {
        const fileStream = await this.s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(downloadParams));
        if (fileStream.Body instanceof Readable){
          fileStream.Body.once('error', err => {
            console.error("Error downloading s3 file")
            console.error(err);
          });

          fileStream.Body.pipe(res);

        }
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error("Error", err);
      }
    };

  run();
  
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html)'s `GetObjectCommand`:

```js
// The following example retrieves an object for an S3 bucket.
const input = {
  "Bucket": "examplebucket",
  "Key": "HappyFace.jpg"
};

const command = new GetObjectCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);

/* response ==
{
  "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
  "ContentLength": "3191",
  "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "ETag": "\"6805f2cfc46c0f04559748bb039d69ae\"",
  "LastModified": "Thu, 15 Dec 2016 01:19:41 GMT",
  "Metadata": {},
  "TagCount": 2,
  "VersionId": "null"
}
*/
// example id: to-retrieve-an-object-1481827837012
```

To stream the body to a file, in Typescript:

```js
import { Readable } from 'stream';

if (!res.Body) {
  throw new Error("No body");
}

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
const readStream = res.Body as Readable;
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```