# How to Store and Access Large Files in NodeJS Web Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, video, large-files

If I want to allow a user to upload a video in a post, then what's the best way to store it so that I can access it later? I am currently just using a INSERT query to upload it to a PostGres SQL database field, but it's extremely slow.

Is there another method or best practice to store large files like this and access it quickly and efficiently?

```
var video = videoFile ? "'\\x" + videoFile.buffer.toString('hex') + "'" : "NULL";
let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO posts (video) VALUES(" + video + ") RETURNING *";
```

Above is the code I'm using right now to insert the file into the database.

Comment: Better provide some code and SQL queries. Otherwise, people would downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store the whole video into the database. These 2 steps below might be a better solution:

1) Upload the video file to the cloud storage. See [Google Cloud Strage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls). There are many other options as well. Go do some comparison yourself.

2) You will have a link or ID (or key in S3) to access a file. Store all those links or ID into your database. Please take a look at this [GCS doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) and this [S3 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143628/nodejs-how-do-i-download-a-file-to-disk-from-an-aws-s3-bucket).

Also, make use of the [non-blocking I/O](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) which is a good thing of node.js. In your case, you may try something like this:

```
let insertQuery;
let promisesList=[];

for(let vid of videoIds){
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO posts (videoId) VALUES($1) RETURNING *";
    promisesList.push(client.query(query,[vid]));
}
await Promise.all();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick follow-up question: what is the difference between using a cloud storage service and postgres database to store large files? How is the cloud storage service significantly faster in both inserting and getting data than SQL queries?