# res.download file from Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, file, express

I am trying to download a file from outside of my root directory however every time I try, it tries to take it from the root directory. I will need the user of my site to be able to download these files.

The file has initially been uploaded to Amazon S3 and I have accessed it using the getObject function.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/test_script_api', function(req, res){
    var fileName = req.query.File;
    s3.getObject(
        { Bucket: "bucket-name", Key: fileName },
        function(error, s3data){
            if(error != null){
                console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
            }else{
                //I have tried passing the S3 data but it asks for a string
                res.download(s3data.Body);

                //So I have tried just passing the file name & an absolute path
                res.download(fileName);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

This returns the following error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/ec2-user/environment/test2.txt'

When I enter an absolute path it just appends this onto the end of /home/ec2-user/environment/

How can I change the directory res.download is trying to download from?

Is there an easier way to download your files from Amazon S3?

Any help would be much appreciated here!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found this answer:
[NodeJS How do I Download a file to disk from an aws s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143628/nodejs-how-do-i-download-a-file-to-disk-from-an-aws-s3-bucket)

Based on that, you need to use createReadStream() and pipe().
R here more about stream.pipe() - https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/

res.attachment() will set the headers for you.
 -> https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.attachment.

This code should work for you (based on the answer in the above link):

```
app.get('/test_script_api', function (req, res) {
  var fileName = req.query.File;
  res.attachment(fileName);
  var file = s3.getObject({
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: fileName
    }).createReadStream()
      .on("error", error => {
      });
   file.pipe(res);
});
```

In my case, on the client side, I used `<a href="URL to my route" download="file name"></a>`
This made sure that the file is downloading.