# Retrieve images from AWS S3 in react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm receiving urls like those from backend:

```
"https://s3.servauto.fr/compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp"
```

it's not the exact url it's just an example, but I changed only the domain.
I'm getting this if trying to access url from browser:

```
  <Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied.</Message>
    <Key>a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5- 
    00155dc60818.webp</Key>
    <BucketName>compression- 
    img</BucketName>
    <Resource>/compression-img/a5d6898a- 
    382c-11ee-bbb5- 
    00155dc60818.webp</Resource>
    <RequestId>178EEB9E92B1E64A
    </RequestId>
    <HostId>4796f121e6ce1a5f5c2
    b8cb9130e56d2 75cde7e1bd216cac28e89f
     450d374bd1</HostId>
     </Error>
```

and i'm provided with this informations:

- AccessKey
- SecretKey
- AWS Region
- Service Name

but i don't really understand what i should do to fetch images

I found in some resources that i should use aws-amplify. but in articles they are doing another thing: like authentication, sign in  or uploading photos.
I also found that i can use aws-sdk. But in don't really know what should i do.
Please take into account that i'm unfamiliar with this topic, so i couldn't really try something. I'm not searching for a ready solution but to only understand what should i do like steps or someone explains to me. There is no enough resources about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

***First, is your image public, I mean everybody can access it without authentication?***

**ANSWER IS YES**

You can access your image from your React frontend. [Here is and example using AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html)

**ANSWER IS NO**

If your company has not configured public access, maybe it's because your image should not be available publicly.
In this case, all the info you have (AccessKey, service name, etc.) must be use from a backend (using SDK). Your backend will expose and endpoint (REST API for example). This endpoint will use the AWS SDK to retrieve the image and send it in the response. Your React frontend will call this endpoint to retrieve the image. [Here is an example with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74293131/3580357)

Comment: So the job must be done by backend ? And I should only receive photos and use them ?

Comment: If the image is not public, yes, you must access it from a backend. You can't use secret keys from a frontend, because the frontend is public. If you do so, everybody will be able to find it from the javascript files.

Comment: L_Cleo answer will also work, but only if your image is public

Comment: I'm working as frontend and they provided me with : AccessKey
SecretKey
AWS Region
Service Name,    and the only information is the url that I've received while fetching all cars. So I guess that backend should do all this work and provide me with ready images to show ? Is it correct what did I understand ?

Comment: Why node JS ? I'm doing it in react native ...

Comment: I put node JS as a backend example, but if you're frontend it doesn't apply to you. I suggest you to have a meeting with your backend team: maybe it's not the 1st time they use S3 images so they might help you better than us

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using aws-amplify as you found on the documentation.

In particular to configure just the S3 part you'd have a `aws-exports.js` file looking like this:

```
export const awsConfig = {
     Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: 'bucket-name', // (required) -  Amazon S3 bucket name
      region: 'eu-central-1' // (optional) -  Amazon service region
    }
  }
}
```

And then within your App.js file have the `Amplify.configure(awsConfig);` statement

Once you configured it you can get a signed URL for your image and display it to the user:

```js
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

function RandomView() {
   
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setImageUrl(undefined);
    Storage.get(item.imageKey, { validateObjectExistence: true })
      .then(signedUrl => {
        setImageUrl(signedUrl);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [item]);

  return (
     <Image style={{ width: 64, height: 64, borderRadius: 7 }} source={{ uri: imageUrl }} />
  );
```

The `imageKey` mentioned there is simply the path of the item within the S3 bucket, for example `profile/users/johndoe.png`.

You'll also notice that when you ask for a signed url, unless you otherwise specified, the aws-amplify library will retrieve a signed url for the `public/whatever/is/you/image/key/path`. So if your files in S3 are not restricted to who is logged in, consider storing them within a root `public` folder

Consider also using a placeholder if you don't want to have a blank image while it's loading

If you're not using a public folder then you'll have to manually set the access rules on the S3 bucket. If the backend is sending you an accessKey and secret then the access is probably already set.
To access the S3 bucket at that point you'll have to make sure to be logged in the same 'role' as the one that can access that folder. When you are logged in with cognito the secret and accessKey are automatically handled by amplify. As far as I know it's not suggested to manually send them yourself since they're temporary anyways

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I need a request to fetch images ? Because I'm receiving like an url from backend but I'm not authorized to see images. Is it normal that I have to send requests to fetch photos ? Because in my case I'm fetching cars like 10000 cars from backend and every car has like 10 photos, so I have to like do 100000 requests to receive all photos ? Because I need to show all cats with their photos.

Comment: I updated my answer, make sure you configured amplify correctly AND that your images are within the /public folder as mentioned above

Comment: But this: `"https://s3.servauto.fr/compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp"` is NOT a signed URL. What you can do is parse it and split the host part to get the path to the image `/compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp` and then pass it to the storage.get method.

Comment: Even if i'm getting a presigned URL i have to do this work ? I can't just show the image ? If it's presigned i Can not juste display it in the app without additional steps

Comment: The backend is not sending you a presigned url that's the point. So you have to retrieve it yourself

Comment: Can You please explain how Can i add secretKey and accessKey to retrieve the image, i did like You suggested but i'm receiving : No credentials and it's asking me for poolId and Cognito account

Comment: Storage.get(item.imageKey, { validateObjectExistence: true })
      .then(signedUrl => {
        setImageUrl(signedUrl);
      }) Can You explain this please ? If i'm receiving from backend a presigned URL where should i put it ? Becasuse Storage.get is already getting a presigned URL

Comment: Retrieve myself ? Do you mean sign it myself with sha256 and so on ?

Comment: the backend is not sending you a presigned URL. It's sending you the URL which is different. After getting the presigned url  you can add it in the Image source.uri attribute

Comment: It's asking you for credentials because you'd have to log in to cognito that will automatically set you the secretKey and accessKey. Either the backend sends you the base64 of the image without you having to go through S3 or he passes you the imageKey and you retrieve it yourself through S3 using a proper cognito authentication

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it more comprehensive of the private folders too

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand, in One way you're saying that if i have image Key Amplify will get presigned URL for me, if i have presigned URL than what should i do ? Backend ? Do you mean from S3 server ?

Comment: compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp. Is it the image Key ?

Comment: If i'm getting the presigned URL or i'm signing it myself i have to just put the presigned URL in source={uri:presignedUrl} ? I dont have to fetch it with axios or Amplify storage ?

Comment: Please Can You answer in borh cases ? When i dont have presignedURL , but what if i have presignedURL or i'm signing it myself how Can display the image, what should i do to display the image ?

Comment: It's in the answer, if you already have a presigned url then you just have to skip the Storage.get step and add it in source={{ uri: imageUrl }}

Comment: compression-img/a5d6898a-382c-11ee-bbb5-00155dc60818.webp. Is it the image Key ? I understand if i dont have thé presigned URL and i want to sign it with storage i need to have poolid and cognito account,i can't do it with secretKey and accessKey ?

Comment: exactly, unfortunately that's how amplify decided to implement it since it is the right way to make your app secure. But if these images are public I suggest you move them under a root folder /public this way you need no cognito account to access them. If they're not, again either the backend returns you the presignedUrl  already (which is not what you wrote in your post) or you use a cognito account. a presigned url looks something like this:  https://bucket.com/pathto/image.jpg?x-amz-content-sha256=e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855&x-amz-user-agent=aws-

Comment: Please answer my question if i have presigned URL, do i need poolid and cognito also ? Or only accessKey and secretKey ?

Comment: no, the cognito is just to generate the presigned url